# What is the default value of DIR's /T option?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I need to update a batch script, and before updating it I need to understand its logic.

I found the following line:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir "extract*.csv" /b /a-d /od') do SET newest=%%G
```

As far as I understand it founds the last file into a directory. But `/t` option is not precised here with the order option.

What is the default `/t` value? I want to know if it's the creation date or last access date which is important on this script.

Answer (score 1):

The default value is `W` which means "Last Written" (taken from http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html):

> /T:W   Last Written (default)